# Display woocommerce product gallery to specific post with slider and zoom effect

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, flexslider

I want to display woocommerce product gallery to post page with galleries effect on my custom theme (based twentysixteen).

Status WooCommerce Version : 3.5.1

For display the product gallery, i using the below code:

```
<?php
        if ( ! function_exists( 'wc_get_gallery_image_html' ) ) {
            return;
        }

        global $product;

        $columns           = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails_columns', 4 );
        $post_thumbnail_id = $product->get_image_id();
        $wrapper_classes   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_gallery_classes', array(
            'woocommerce-product-gallery',
            'woocommerce-product-gallery--' . ( $product->get_image_id() ? 'with-images' : 'without-images' ),
            'woocommerce-product-gallery--columns-' . absint( $columns ),
            'images',
            'flex-control-thumbs0',
            'woocommerce-product-gallery__trigger',
        ) );
        ?>
        <div class="<?php echo esc_attr( implode( ' ', array_map( 'sanitize_html_class', $wrapper_classes ) ) ); ?>" data-columns="<?php echo esc_attr( $columns ); ?>" style="opacity: 1; transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;">
            <figure class="woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper">
                <?php
                if ( $product->get_image_id() ) {
                    $html = wc_get_gallery_image_html( $post_thumbnail_id, true );
                } else {
                    $html  = '<div class="woocommerce-product-gallery__image--placeholder">';
                    $html .= sprintf( '<img src="%s" alt="%s" class="wp-post-image" />', esc_url( wc_placeholder_img_src( 'woocommerce_single' ) ), esc_html__( 'Awaiting product image', 'woocommerce' ) );
                    $html .= '</div>';
                }

                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', $html, $post_thumbnail_id ); // phpcs:disable WordPress.XSS.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped

                do_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails' );

                ?>
            </figure>
        </div>
```

The product gallery now already displayed, but just image. Not has effect slider or zoom.

You can see the screenshot of my page on this link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3ZP5.jpg

How i must do for show the effect of slider and zoom?

Answer (score 1):

After WooCommerce 3.0, there is a significant frontend change that can be broken down into three separate new features;

- Image zoom / magnification
- Lightbox
- Slider

To enable each of these features in your theme you must declare support using `add_theme_support()` like so;

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'yourtheme_setup' );

function yourtheme_setup() {
    add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
    add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-lightbox' );
    add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-slider' );
}
```

Code goes in `functions.php`